# How do we feel about homework questions?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48776/why-is-cloud-atlas-named-cloud-atlas), the author clearly states they are asking because they don't know the answer and it's part of their homework for school. I love to answer questions when I can, but should there be any kind of "ethical" or "moral" standard to what should or shouldn't be answered? *It seems kind of shady to help someone cheat*. I'm sure it happens more often, but when the admission is in the body of the question, that's a different story.

I'm no high-ground holier-than-thou type, but it gave me pause and thought I'd ask what the community thought.

Comment: I'd prefer that questions were treated on their own merits.  Punishing a user for who they are or why/how they ask it detrimental to building good content.

Comment: The OP claims to have checked Wikipedia: "Wow, I actually read the summary on Wikipedia for additional details," but missed the relevant bit they were searching for and upvoted the Wiki answer. This does not seem like good content, *but I do take your point*. The two SE's I'm most active on rarely mention that it's for homework; I'd imagine that math/science stacks encounter this with more regularity. **The OP could have at least said "thanks for doing my homework."** ;)

Comment: Yeah, but if it's a bad unresearched question then it's a bad unresearched question no matter why he was failing to do the research.  And since General Reference is no longer a thing, I believe that means you should downvote and move on.

Comment: I didn't even downvote, I was just curious if anyone else had thoughts on the subject.

Comment: A valid question is a valid question is a valid question.

Comment: @Richard: ...but only between Ferengi.

Comment: I generally choose not to answer homework questions. I pretty much only answer Harry Potter questions -- I'm not going to find merit in a question asking *Help! I was suppose to read Goblet of Fire by today! What are the major plot points of Goblet of Fire? What parts of the book did you like best?* This question was actually asked here a couple of years ago. I did ask that particular user to please do their own work, but mostly I ignore obvious homework questions.

Comment: @Slytherincess That's pretty much what I did, too. Didn't answer it, didn't downvote. (Whenever I see a HP question answered by someone else, I'm like "did Slytherincess die or something?" ;)

Comment: @MeatTrademark -- Haha, no, I'm alive and well, lurking in the Slytherin dungeons :)) If I don't answer an HP question, it's because either 1) it already has a good, solid accepted answer, 2) I think the question is silly, 3) the answer is easily Googleable, 4) the question is unclear, a duplicate, or clearly trollicious, or 5) I'm too lazy (a frequent occurrence, admittedly). No, I haven't kicked it yet (Sing it, haters!!!!). I'm far too stubborn for that ;)

Comment: +1 for at least following [The Law of Fives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discordianism#Law_of_Fives). :)

Comment: I've amended the question title to make it easier for searching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main SE site has gone over homework ad nauseum, but the official stance is summed up pretty nicely at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

I think we should pretty much mirror that stance.

**Whether I'm asking about Wolverine's love life out of pure curiosity or seeking an answer for a paper has zero relevance on whether or not it is either a good question or if it is off-topic.**

In this case, a downvote would be perfectly understandable since the asker even admitted to reading the same page I did and just missed the pertinent information.

Comment: Good enough. I was just curious what the consensus was as I hadn't seen both someone admitting it was for homework, **and** either missing the pertinent info, or lying about evening checking for it.

Comment: I'd love to take a class that grades on knowing Wolverine's love life.