# Should we have a policy on questions about adult topics in SFF?

Tags: discussion, scope, question-quality

While we have a [long](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1582/31394)-[standing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3046/31394) [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/31394) that it's OK to ask about adult topics here - everything from sex to rape to bestiality - there have also been quite a number of questions in recent years which have stirred up controversy and disagreement within the community as to how they should be handled. Even mods exercising their discretion to close or delete such questions has often been met with resistance. For example:

- [Has George R. R. Martin described the color of Daenerys' pubic hair in any book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/142810/31394) - VTCed, deleted, undeleted; [ensuing meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10251/31394).
- [Did Draco Malfoy sexually assault Hermione Granger?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144298/31394) - closed, deleted, reopened, undeleted, closed, deleted, undeleted, deleted; [ensuing meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10317/31394).
- [Godfather, Sirius Black - Dogfather as well?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/181283/31394) - closed, reopened, closed, deleted, undeleted, had more VTROs but now 2 VTDs; [ensuing meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11704/31394).

Mod-deletion of such questions isn't a new thing: e.g. see [What's the stamina of Wolverine on bed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83396/31394) from 2015, although in that case the community [seemed fairly unanimous against the question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6691/31394) and it didn't cause much controversy. On the other hand, we've also had many questions about sex and even [rape and bestiality in children's books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15382/31394) which have been well-received. Even recently, we have a [clear policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11441/31394) that being about erotica shouldn't be a reason to consider story-ID questions off-topic.

Many of these questions have attracted custom moderator flags going *both* ways: some people flag to say "this question is inappropriate and should be deleted" and others flag to say "this question is bad but on-topic and should be reopened/undeleted". With so much disagreement among the community on each individual case (as evidenced by the close/reopen and delete/undelete wars on many of these questions), it's hard for moderators to know how to handle such flags. Obviously we won't be able to keep *everyone* happy no matter what, but ideally it would be nice to have a clear meta policy on questions of this type, which we can point to when taking action on them or handling people's flags.

Ideas I've seen proposed in comments include:

- that there should be some form of **notability** (e.g. "was Umbridge raped by centaurs" is OK because this is a widely-known fan theory, but "did Sirius Black have sex with female dogs" isn't because it's not a notable claim that he did) - but we don't have any such requirement for any other types of question, so this unprecedented criterion would require a clear meta consensus;
- that the question should be asked **in good faith** (e.g. questions which appear to be posted just for shock or titillation value aren't OK, but questions springing from genuine curiosity about a work of SFF are) - but judging an OP's motivation is always difficult, and even mods, who are more used to making such judgement calls, have often been called out on meta for exercising their discretion on such questions.

**What should our policy be on how to treat questions on 'adult topics' like this? When should they be closed or deleted as opposed to simply downvoted?**

Please propose and vote on possible policies below!

---

> ### EDIT to summarise the conclusion

After much debate, the voting has settled in favour of [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11733/31394) (now +24/-3; the [second answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11729/31394) is +19/-10 and says something similar, and the [third answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11732/31394) is +15/-8). Executive summary:

- adult topics should never be a reason to close or delete an otherwise on-topic question;
- as always, downvotes are yours to use as you choose;
- any unnecessary prurience can be edited out if it doesn't affect the thrust of the question.

Following this policy, I've reopened the two Harry Potter questions from the bullet points above. In future, if you see questions of this type getting closed incorrectly, feel free to flag them (perhaps with a link to this meta) for mod reopening and locking if necessary.

Comment: With many of these questions, especially the examples you gave which made it to big meta fame, the problem doesn't seem to be the "adult content" per se, but the way in which they approached it. This also seems to be at the base of their controversy. The people who looked beyond simple yes/no on-topic rules realized that those specific questions were highly problematic, while others felt a rather general on-topic policy for mature content violated and protested accordingly. So, while a noble goal, I doubt a *general* rule for "adult content" would prevent similar controversies in the future.

Comment: As long as you only look at the topicality and *not* the surrounding circumstances, you're unlikely to solve this issue. But of course as soon as you look beyond mere scope, it also becomes highly subjective and I doubt you'd find a clear-cut policy that prevents *just the "right"* questions from getting downvoted/closed/deleted. Neither will pointing close-voters at a general "these things are on-topic!" consensus stop people from wanting crap and troll questions gone.

Comment: @TARS Well, this is why I've tried to link to as many specific examples as possible. Maybe the problem with a simple "adult content is OK, but troll questions aren't" policy is that there are too many grey-area cases which weren't covered clearly enough. Maybe we can come up with a new policy which, even if it doesn't *eliminate* controversy over specific questions, will at least *reduce* it.

Comment: I think its interesting how the examples cited were received. Only one question has a positive score (and a high score, at that). The question also arguably doesn't have the explicit content as the *focus*; rather, the focus is "what happened to Umbridge", while acknowledging that rape or assault was a possibility raised elsewhere. The questions that are clearly focused on the sexuality, rather than details of plot or story, were heavily down voted.

Comment: I guess I agree with TARS, 'adult topics' is too broad and vague to come up with a good consensus. Perhaps tighten-down the scope? I mean, we already have discussions about adult content and the supposed [minimum] age gate.

Comment: Perhaps what you meant was "Should we have a policy on questions about f***ed up adult topics in SFF?"

Comment: We have a policy. It's "*Questions about it's sex and sexuality are fine, but **don't use the site to satisfy your weird urges***".

Comment: @Valorum `Questions about it's sex and sexuality are fine, but don't use the site to satisfy your weird urges` -i am actually afraid that we were too quick to label the OP of the animagi question of being werid/ some kind of sexual deviant when he asked an unfortunately formulated question about animagi. As far as i remember his other questions were PG with no signs of trolling.

Comment: @Morrigan - The way that it was *[originally worded](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/53c77545-f3e4-4e8b-9769-06c763a45b8f/view-source)* was much less appropriate. It's not actually that much better now after have had most of the offending content removed

Comment: @Valorum well, it's not very eloquent... but the reason can be OP not being fluent in English (i am afraid i have the same problem) or not very good at expressing himself in writing...

Comment: @Morrigan - The question is dire and the response, I felt was proportionate.

Comment: @Valorum perhaps. As Rand writes it's not easy to judge the OP's intentions...

Comment: @Möoz I share your doubt about whether the phrase "adult topics" adequately covers the scope of what's being asked about here, but I couldn't think of a better way to describe this category of questions. If you can think of a better description, let me know!

Comment: @Valorum Given the amount of controversy over the linked example questions, you can't possibly say we have a clear policy already :-) Who judges whether a question is "us[ing] the site to satisfy [the OP's] weird urges", as opposed to a genuine question? If even moderators are going to get called out on meta each time they make that judgement, then it seems we need a clearer policy.

Comment: `"Questions about it's sex and sexuality are fine, but don't use the site to satisfy your weird urges"`. Link please, @Valorum, I've never seen this policy. And a [quick search](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22weird+urges%22) doesn't find anything either.

Comment: From what I've seen the controversy isn't that people like/dislike the questions (as most appear to dislike them) but that they have a problem with using close/delete votes as super downvotes.

Comment: @Beofett While the community response to those questions is of interest, it's also a response only to some of what the community saw as "controversial". In a previous discussion, I linked [a set of other adult-topic questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3047/5184) that all had positive scores - including one with a net +47.

Comment: *I share your doubt about whether the phrase "adult topics" adequately covers the scope of what's being asked about here, but I couldn't think of a better way to describe this category of questions.* This was one of the major problems in the earlier discussion, and I think the real problem here - everyone keeps saying "adult content/topics", but no one is willing to clearly define what that means or what they're referring to. In the past, it was kicked off by interspecies-sex, as are these discussions. Maybe *that's* what the discussion should be focused on.

Comment: **Fun fact:** it's not unprecedented for an SE site to have special requirements for questions on one particular topic which aren't reflected in general for all questions. I learned today that [History SE has a policy that it's OK to judge questions about Nazis or the Holocaust more harshly than other questions](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3682), and for the community to use all the tools at their disposal (including VTCs/flags) on such questions if they suspect them. We could in principle have different requirements for questions about adult topics than for anything else.

Comment: @phantom42 Only some of the controversial questions have been about interspecies sex. We also have one about a character's pubic hair, and one about whether one (human) character raped another. I'm hoping for a policy which can cover all of these cases.

Comment: Fair, but I think the point remains - some sort of definition of "adult content/topics" or just *what* is so offensive has to be established here before we can really decide on a policy to blanketly cover all cases.

Comment: As a fan of at least [one author known for adult material, "weird urges" included](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jacqueline-carey) (I really wish I could come up with good questions), I would very much like to find a balance point.  I have zero interest in supporting questions about fictional crotches, or enabling someones wank slashfic theory.  I have every interest in supporting questions about sex, or sexual content.  I think it's fair that these questions should have extra scrutiny to pass muster, or possibly wider editing to bring them within a standard.

Comment: I'll voice some of my concerns differently here. A lot of the proposed solutions seem to be coming from the intent of the question rather than about the question itself. Consider the following 2 examples: 1. "I really want to know what character X's pubes look like, do we know what colour they are?" 2. "Character X'. pubes make up a significant plot element because of Y. Later on Z implies the colour is the reason, do we know what the colour is?" Both questions are "What colour are the pubes?" yet the intent is different....

Comment: Considering the questions are identical I don't see how 1. can be off topic yet 2. on topic. The intent should not classify whether a question is on topic or not and that is also a very subjective close reason. I personally don't see how you can separate these questions into what's too much adult content.

Comment: After all what might be disgusting and weird to you could be someone's Tuesday afternoon.

Comment: For a more concrete example of my questions consider the following extreme ASOIAF questions 1. "Young Griff is described as muscular and handsome and really get's my juices flowing, do we know if his pubes are described?" 2. "Young Griff has died purple hair and is claiming to be Aegon son of Rhaegar. The baby Aegon allegedly had the Targaryen traits (silver blonde hair) and Dany is described as having silver pubes. Do we know if fAegon's pubes are described as they could solve the mystery?" Both Q's being what colour are fAegon's pubes? but different intent.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - well, I don't consider discussion of someone's personal juices to be a good fit for the site.  So I see two very different questions.  I get the point you're trying to make, but I think this is pretty much exactly what needs to be cut out.

Comment: @Radhil you realise they've just gone to one extreme to make a point. No one, to date, has ever described their juices.

Comment: @Radhil Well the thing is both questions are "What colour are fAegon's pubes?" Any offending content can be edited but the questions remain the same. Also as Ed says I went to the extremes to make my point.

Comment: And the point remains - fundamentally, they're the same question. The difference is in the wording.

Comment: Then we either need someone willing to edit such questions to remove that difference, or acknowledge we need to close them until the user does so.

Comment: @Radhil Anyone who CV's a question because of "get's my juices flowing" has the power to edit that out and should do so rather than CVing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot an editor should not be changing the intent of a question, it is even a reject reason. To completely reword and add in your own knowledge and research is changing the intent of the question.

Comment: @Skooba I said remove the offending content not reword, add research or change the intent.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sometimes the wording of a question moves it from "genuine question" into the territory of "trolling". Consider the following ACTUAL example from the site: title "*Does green kryptonite also affect non-living kryptonian objects?*", question body "*I was planning to rape Supergirl with my friends [...] very easy after putting her under green kryptonite radiation [...] some of us have doubts that we'd be unable to [tear] her clothes apart.*" Should a question like that be edited, or simply nuked?

Comment: **We should make it abundantly clear that we're not talking about regular old adult content; we're talking about the _clearly_ prurient and extreme content.**

Comment: You say that, @mooz - but I don't see the "dog father" question as being "clearly prurient" or "extreme content".

Comment: @phantom42 At the moment or at all?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well that's a different situation from what we're talking about here and trolling covers all questions not just adult content ones. If you want a policy for trolling ask a separate meta on it, though I can already tell you the consensus would be nuke them. However, here we are talking about adult content which mostly hasn't fallen under the trolling area yet.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Your "gets my juices flowing" example could also be seen as a troll question. I think part of the problem here may be that there's a sector of questions which *some* people see as trolling/inappropriate and *some* people see as genuine questions.

Comment: @Möoz The problem is that what's "clearly" prurient to one person could be an acceptable question to someone else. If everyone had the same standard for such things, this whole discussion would be much easier.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well as stated above I was using an extreme to get my point across. But in that example it's not the adult content that's the problem it's the trolling. I do agree that no one will agree on how much is too much because we all have different levels.

Answer (score 23):

### The rules are fine as-is.

Reference:

- [Should questions about sex and other adult activities be off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3043/5184)
- [What's our tolerance for adult content?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1582/5184)

#### But phantom, there are so many arguments!

Hey, I didn't say that the whole situation is good - just that the rules are fine. Let's back up.

Based on the existing guidelines, adult content and topics are OK.

My answer on one of the previous questions mentioned that I was OK with the questions

> [so] long as the question is written with a reasonable level of maturity and lack of vulgarity.

This answer was a net +25 score, with only one dissenter (likely the OP). The net +33 score did not establish any qualifications for questions, just saying that the content was OK.

#### But clearly the existing rules aren't working! So many arguments!

Some of these questions *are* kind of tasteless. Others are not. Some questions about sex and sexuality have high question scores and good responses.

So what's the difference between them? My very scientific research of looking at comments that are still available, and my ultra-reliable memory of comments that are gone shows us a few themes that keep popping up.

- > terrible, borderline-offensive questions
- > I'm voting to delete. Given the lack of notability in the claim, these sorts of questions could be asked endlessly.
- > Prurient questions about bestiality are not suitable for a site aimed at a 13+ fanbase.
- > It's got nothing to do with the subject matter, it's just a lousy question that deserved to be closed and deleted.
- > Since it was a sexual question, failed any notability standards (link to plot, link to characters, link to SFF elements, etc)

So, based on negative comments, it seems that there is no question about them being "on-topic" - it's a matter of content. Primarily, either the content is poor, or the notability is low.

**Low-Quality**

Historically, we don't close questions just for being low quality. If the question is on-topic, it remains open and we downvote them as we see fit.

**Notability**

We are not [skeptics.se], and we've never had a "notability" requirement before, so I'm not really sure where all this is coming from. A bad, or poorly researched question is bad, or poorly researched question - and users are free to downvote them as they see fit, but they are on-topic. In our previous discussion [How do we handle questions based on incorrect premise?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5184), we decided that no special handling was needed. Either downvote, or attempt to correct OP either via comments or through an answer.

**Prurient Questions (Intent)**

As LethalCarrot points out [in comments](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11728/should-we-have-a-policy-on-questions-about-adult-topics-in-sff#comment38540_11728), the same question can seem more/less prurient just by changing the wording and provided background of the question.

> 1. "Young Griff is described as muscular and handsome and really get's my juices flowing, do we know if his pubes are described?"
> 2. "Young Griff has died purple hair and is claiming to be Aegon son of Rhaegar. The baby Aegon allegedly had the Targaryen traits (silver blonde hair) and Dany is described as having silver pubes. Do we know if Aegon's pubes are described as they could solve the mystery?"
>
> Both Q's being what colour are Aegon's pubes? but different intent.

We've had discussions before (I can't find it on meta right now, it may have just been in chat) about removing "extra fluff" from questions - stuff like, "I was watching this movie and it made me think about..." because it's extraneous and has no bearing on the question. Also because it often clouds the intent of the question. But based on our discussion [How do we feel about homework questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3319/5184), intent and reasoning behind asking a question is irrelevant.

> Whether I'm asking about Wolverine's love life out of pure curiosity or seeking an answer for a paper has zero relevance on whether or not it is either a good question or if it is off-topic.

---

#### So they're not off-topic by policy, but clearly people don't want these questions.

And yet, no one has articulated *why* or exactly what it is that they don't want. Instead, people are using the close/delete flags as super-downvotes.

---

#### So, what do we do?

People are always going to use close/delete flags as super-downvotes. Even if we have a meta-established policy, it's just going to happen. Either people will disagree with the policy and continue, or people won't be aware of the policy. Policy should not change here. The policy itself is fine.

#### OK, so what do *the mods* do?

Follow existing policy. So long as the questions aren't vulgar or intentionally offensive, ask yourself "is the question itself on topic?" and act accordingly.

#### So don't do *anything*?

I'm not sure I'd actively support a movement to remove all extra fluff from questions, but I think trimming down controversial elements that don't make a huge impact on the crux of the question would be justifiable in situations like these.

Comment: I think there is plenty of articulating what and why we don't it! ;-)

Comment: I agree 100%. The _topic_ of the question should not be an issue. The _wording_ of the question does not need to be vulgar or egregiously offensive just because it's asking about adult content. Banning adult content outright would eliminate a _lot_ of genuinely serious discussions about sf/f material (see, for example, the _Thomas Covenant_ series).

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head here +1

Comment: The case of editing is a curious one, too, though. I remember the crisis around the infamous Captain America question (linked here somewhere, too), when people actually tried to salvage the question with edits (becuase it couldn't be closed, of course), only to have their edits rolled back by other users who saw them violating the OP's intent (of...asking a bad question, I guess). There seems to be a general hesitation on both sides to make any kind of compromise in controversial cases for fear of violating the hypothetical *general* case.

Comment: I think that was [the drama over the bifrost question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6707/5184), but yeah, it definitely has the potential to cause its own issues.

Comment: @phantom42 Nah, it was the gay thing, and it was not the OP, but the *other* equally offended (by the question) users who rolled back the edits since it seemed to be some all-or-nothing scenario where you can either keep the question in all its awfulness or have it be cleansed from the face of the site entirely.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that bit. No great loss.

Comment: We do have a notability requirement, it's just not referenced a lot. - "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*"

Comment: See [What problems does answering a question on this site solve?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/5184), [Are we really here to solve problems?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1380/5184), and [Can we please fix the About page to remove “actual problem” and “practical” wording?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3068/5184). tl;dr: we're not here to solve "actual problems".

Comment: From a practical point of view, if this answer becomes policy, what would we (either community or mods) actually be doing? Reopening/undeleting such questions if they get closed/deleted, locking them if necessary (since the same users can VTD as many times as they want), and editing them to improve wording/intent if possible? Would the usual rules about preserving OP's intent apply to such edits, or would we be able to make more drastic edits than usual for the cause of removing salaciousness?

Comment: To choose to edit one of those questions assumes good faith, I for one can't do that, especially for the likes of the couple of questions recently in question.

Comment: Reopening/undeleting/locking as necessary - yes. I'm a little torn, myself, on the whole editing thing - I know that can get dicey. My *thought* is just to excise bits that don't actually make up the question - we often don't need to know background as to why the user is asking the question, or what made them think of the question. The goal is to preserve or distill the question without upsetting everyone. I know this isn't always going to be possible - some users are going to resist. There is never going to be a magic cure-all answer.

Comment: *Can* users keep re-voting to delete? I know you can only vote to re-open once.

Comment: "Can users keep re-voting to delete?" For some effing reason, yes. See for example [this revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/114500/revisions). That's why these questions so often need to be locked, because otherwise *the same people* could keep on deleting/undeleting indefinitely :-/ [Relevant main meta post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9431/278659)

Comment: @phantom42 Delete votes operate under a different set of rules. They're more restricted and less common that close votes. You only get 5 at 10k and get one per 1k until you cap out at 30 per day(35k rep). And if you review the LQP for deletion, it eats those first for some reason. Close and reopen are once per question (unless the close ages away)

Comment: @phantom42 - for extra irony, some of the hated-on questions are actually one of the very few ones on here that solve actual problem (someone's writing a fanfic and needs help). Mind you, that doesn't necessarily improve their quality, just meta irony quotent.

Comment: TLDR: yes, they're on-topic, nobody has ever said otherwise, but the problem is that they're crap questions and Stack Exchange keeps higher standards on its content quality. Sport is having the same discussion about one of our topics (of course nowhere near as ire-raising as this one) and the apparent direction is the same: on-topic is necessary but not sufficient to allow some questions to stay. They have to be good questions too.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Yes, please do that.  Just because people who ought to know better start breaking the rules, does not mean you stop enforcing them.  (Also, if *the same* users repeatedly break the rules, maybe have a private word with those users?)

Comment: **Thank you** for miraculously managing to draw a voting consensus out of this contentious debate. I've added a brief summary of your conclusions to the OP; let me know if I've misrepresented anything.

Answer (score 11):

Adult content is on-topic, but does need to treated with more scrutiny.

I think the question body here hits on the two points I agree with most... **Notability and Good Faith.**

<sub>To see what I think the policy should be, skip to the bottom</sub>

The two ideas really go hand in hand. If you can show even a small amount of research as to why you are asking the question it usually demonstrate the same level of good faith. If you throw a two sentence question about two characters that don't interact much, and there is not even a slight implication from the source to confirm it, it makes me question why you asking the question.

Question on these topics tend to fall into the latter. What I notice is that people like to play [Jump-to-Conclusions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42WNHGr1jGI); they take antecedal evidence and use to it to make claims that almost, *almost* make sense but crumble under any type of scrutiny.

---

**Example 1:**

[Is Captain America gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay) : The lowest voted question that remains not deleted (due to a moderator lock). It takes random evidence and forces a conclusion for the answers to confirm or deny. **No notability and no good faith.**

**Counter Example 1:**

[In the films, was the portrayal of Captain America supposed to come across as gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170604/in-the-films-was-the-portrayal-of-captain-america-supposed-to-come-across-as-ga) : While a controversial question itself, it maintained a positive score. It provides credible evidence from primary sources to reach a conclusion for the answers to expand and provide further evidence. **Notability and good faith.**

---

**Example 2:**

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181283/godfather-sirius-black-dogfather-as-well : I think that the question that sparked this meta also provides the best example of this plays out. The question provided not a stitch of evidence that this had happened nor why even why they might think it did. **No notability and no good faith**.

**Counter Example 2:**

[What exactly did Aberforth Dumbledore do to the goats?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39576/what-exactly-did-aberforth-dumbledore-do-to-the-goats) - This question is also about the same touchy subject, but since it provides a reference from the work that gives evidence to the situation it was very well received. **Notability and good faith**.

---

There many, many other examples like the ones shown. A question asked in good faith and that shows notability to the claim are well received. A question that does neither is not well received.

### Posts should be required to show a minimal level of effort. This applies to all questions, but should particularly apply to questions that deal with adult topics.

### Questions that do not meet quality standards can an should be removed. Again, this applies to all questions, but should particularly apply to questions that deal with adult topics.

This will not solve all problems. We regularly have meta discussion on just the closing of questions as duplicates, too broad, or primarily opinion based. I don't think any "policy" is going to change that. These discussion about closing and deleting are still going to happen.  However, in the end this may give a starting point as to why...

### Users with moderator tool privileges should close and delete these questions.

**To be clear I am not advocating adult content be off-topic, only that it meet the same standards as any other post. The only difference is that since it is questionable content, it needs to be removed instead of just "downvoted-to-heck".

Comment: I think this is an excellent approach.  Removing posts that do not meet our quality standards should be an ongoing effort. Preserving them under misguided aversion to "super-downvotes" is harmful to our site.

Comment: I think again a problem that this "policy" has is that fundamentally both questions are the same, if one is off topic the other should be too. If you don't agree with the intent DV do not use a super DV. You can always edit the question to be in better shape but don't close it just because you don't like what you *believe* the OPs intentions are.

Comment: The problem here is that you arbitrarely assume good and bad faith, in a subjective manner (mostly - whether consciously or not - based on whether you like the poster, from my experience). I was accused of bad faith posting (as in, called a troll) on SFF before. This sort of attitude is one of the reasons I chose to disengage from the site.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Why is it up to the community to make questions acceptable? It is one thing to make minor edits that remove ambiguity or certain phrases that make a question seem off-topic, and completely another to try do the OPs research for them.

Comment: @Skooba I'm not suggesting doing the OP's research for them, that's for answers. I'm saying that assuming good and bad faith and using that to close a question is wrong.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To What is subjective about a site's quality standards? Are we just supposed to allow any post survive just because it is "on-topic"?

Comment: @Skooba Yes because close votes are not super downvotes. If you don't agree with the question downvote it, that is what they are for.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I am using basic measures of quality and effort to close questions.

Comment: @Skooba Yes but quality is subjective and close voting is meant to be objective. What may be low quality to you may be high quality to someone else. What may be bad faith for you could be good faith for someone else.

Comment: @Skooba - yes. We do ***exactly*** that for all OTHER posts that don't offend you based on subject matter. They may get downvoted for lack of research but don't get VTCd/deleted. ever.

Comment: DVK & Lethal So we are just supposed to allow offensive material to stay on the site without question? I personally don't find swear words offensive, but if I start dropping F-bombs around, I am going to have a bad time... All things offensive can be considered objective.

Comment: Offensive and adult content are two different matters. Offensive usually violates the Be Nice policy and is eligible to be flagged.

Comment: *The question provided not a stitch of evidence that this had happened nor why even why they might think it did.* The original version of the question provided some of that. The OP edited it out to focus on his actual question when people vtc'ing it as unclear.

Comment: @ibid "Dumbldedore read Sirius' will, so of course he must like bestiality in Animagus form!" That falls in the same category as "Captain American didn't rape Black Widow, he must be gay!".

Comment: @Skooba - Not saying they were *good* reasons, but to say the OP didn't "even [explain] why they might think [so ]" is a bit misleading.

Comment: **How can "good faith" be defined?** Usually mods are entrusted to judge such things, but even we've been called out for closing/deleting overly sexual questions. Taking your Counter Example 1: I don't remember who the OP was (the post is now anonymised), but I'm reasonably sure it's someone who was well aware of the previous "Captain America gay" question, and *potentially* the motive for posting it might have been to stir more controversy by rekindling a previously controversial discussion/post. I do recall at least one mod flag on that question saying it was basically a troll post.

Answer (score 9):

We already have such a policy:

- If a question is on an adult topic, **it's on-topic**. No ifs, ends or buts.

  Also, "weird" "urges" is entirely in the eye of the beerholder. Some people like [Carey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jacqueline-carey) and slashfics. Some people like My Little Pony. Some people like fiction that praises genocydal tyrants. Some people like Pokemon. Let's be a wee bit more tolerant here and not marginalize people based on our own subjective morality sense<sup>[1]</sup>.
- If a question is bad, you downvote it. **VTC and delete are not super-downvotes**.
- If a question violates the "be nice policy", it needs to be either edited to fix that, or in worst case scenario, deleted. According to general moderation principles, the former is preferred.

  Please note that this addresses the concerns over "tone", expressed in another answer. If the question has a poor tone, editing that tone out is usually not that hard.
- Unless someone invents real world mind reading machine, there is almost<sup>[2]</sup> no legitimate way to generically determine the intent of the poster. So "it was a troll" or "it was to satisfy weird urges" (thank you very much for marginalizing people with unusual sexuality) is a personal subjective opinion of individual users, NOT a statement of objective fact that can be used to base a moderation decision on.

  This "no guessing intentions" is a policy on Skeptics, both regarding content itself (no questions asking about intentions) AND, more importantly, as I was repeatedly told by Skeptics moderators, regarding Meta issues (shouldn't assume site users' intentions). Over time, I have learned the wisdom of such an approach.

<sub>[1] - OK, let's marginalize people who like Twilight. I'm down for that</sub>.

<sub>[2] - there are some very rare exceptional cases where the poster openly confirms their intentions - e.g. via a comment. In that case, it's quite OK to apply anti-troll policies</sub>

Comment: Could you elaborate on this "no guessing intentions" idea? Either by explaining why it's a good idea, or linking to other posts (maybe on Skeptics meta?) which explain it. Just the fact that it's a policy on Skeptics will cut no ice here, I suspect :-)

Comment: According to this answer, any question in the form of "has this character engaged in this sexual act" can be made on topic by adding "is there any evidence in canon".  There has to be some way to draw a line between reasonable content and blatantly trolling fetish material.

Comment: What exactly are you defending here?

Comment: `there are some very rare exceptional cases where the poster openly confirms their intentions` We haven't seen, and I'd doubt we'd ever see anyone come along and say "Hey guys, Troll, here, has Sirius ever..." So yeah, our best option is to try and determine their motives by the very little we have to go by, which is the content of their post.

Comment: `If a question is on an adult topic, it's ontopic. No ifs ends or buts.` Yes there are; don't forget, we have a possibility of 13 year olds using this site. Besides, the particular Harry Potter question is asking about a work aimed at children.

Comment: `VTC and dedlete are not super-downvotes.` In these extreme cases, no one uses the VTC button as a super-dv, rather as it's intended: to close bad questions.

Comment: `This "no guessing intentions" is a policy on Skeptics` Huh? How often does someone ask about female characrers' pubes, or whether Animagi have sexual relations leading to offspring, on Skeptics? We are not them, besides.

Comment: I feel like we're arguing the merits of the _way_ these extreme questions get closed/down-voted/deleted, and we're forgetting that those types of questions enter the realm of "It's a f***ed up question, who cares how/why it gets closed, just nuke it to oblivion"...

Comment: Lastly, I'm sorry if what Valorum commented on offended you (I agree, he can be harsh and terse, and he should just quit and donate his rep to me), but please don't write a drawn-out rant disguised as an answer instead of using the comment button.

Comment: +1, while not perfect, this answer sums up the questions and how they should be handled. @Möoz ` rather as it's intended: to close bad questions.` That's not what it's for. It's for closing questions which are off-topic, duplicates, opinion-based or too broad. In cases where no off-topic reasons fit but the question _is_ off-topic (as stated via a policy) the other button may be used. This is the opportunity to actually make these questions off-topic, write an answer out-lining a policy, rather than "I don't like them and neither do these people so NUKE!"

Comment: @Möoz unfortunately, though, the *way* things get closed/deleted is what ticks people off and calls them to defend those posts out of principle, which is why this meta exists afterall.

Comment: I am delighted to marginalise people who're interested in asking questions about bestiality (in the context of children's book, no less) on a site aimed at users that are 13+

Comment: @TARS - THAT. Thank you. I'm deeply unhappy and uncomfortable with "the ends justify the means" approach.

Comment: In my experience and observation, trying to salvage troublesome posts with edits usually leads to _more_ issues, not less. Rollbacks or defensiveness from the OP, other users arguing about what to edit, or arguments about whether the edits are enough. Users even get pissed off when you suggest they edit the question themselves. It's much easier, and much less of a hassle, to cast a close vote for whichever reason best fits and hope that 4 other like-minded individuals do the same, instead of becoming embroiled in user moderation drama. Until we can fix that, there's going to be problems.

Comment: @Valorum - If the supposed bestiality *had* occurred in the work, I don't think you'd be advocating for getting rid of questions about it. (It is a pointless, prurient, and unmotivated question as it is, though).  It's not our job to conceal sexuality (including its harmful aspects) from teenagers, and I think attempts to do so are counterproductive anyway. IPS doesn't try to hide questions about things like sexual assault and suicide, for example. And of course, practically speaking *any* site on the Internet is accessible to people of any age, pretensions of age limits aside.

Comment: @Valorum - For example, we can and should ask what Aberforth did with goats. Even if he didn't engage in bestiality (and Rowling kind of says he didn't), that's still the joke. And it's in the same series....

Comment: @Adamant - Indeed. And such a question has good notability too. Whereas the question "***Does Aberforth have sex with his goats?"*** is intentionally provocative, even if it's theoretically on topic

Answer (score 6):

## Questions should be more than just the poster's speculation

I think we can all agree [this deleted question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/did-draco-malfoy-sexually-assault-hermione-granger) is terrible

> I've been lead to believe that their is a scene in either the book or the movie were Hermione is raped/sexually assaulted by Malfoy, did this actually happen?

Questions that simply speculate without any other references should be closed. The problem here isn't the adult nature, or even the speculation, it's the fact that there's nothing but the OP speculating. I don't think anyone wants a site full of [questions like this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/could-the-enterprise-beam-a-vampire-into-a-house-she-didn-t-have-permission-to-e).

This tends to be more prevalent in the adult realm, in that a lot of subject material (Harry Potter, LOTR, Star Wars, etc) never crosses that line into porn. For instance, we see Wolverine romancing women (and even bedding them), but we're never shown what happens in the NSFW realm (and it's highly unlikely Marvel would ever cross that line). Thus, [asking us to estimate Wolverine's stamina in said situations](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/how-to-make-this-question-suitable-for-this-site) leaves us with little but the speculation of the answerers. I would say we need to be just a bit more strict on adult questions for this reason. Promoting pure speculation on adult situations can go downhill really quick.

## NSFW links should only answer questions

Generally speaking [NSFW links are not acceptable on SO/SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281251/how-should-we-handle-links-to-adult-content-in-posts). Since we're crafting policy for a site that discusses it, links to potentially NSFW material should warn people so they know what they're getting into up front (and ONLY to answer the question). [SO really doesn't like exposing people to that stuff unintentionally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362493/nsfw-triage-review-audit/362506#362506)

## Treat sensitive issues sensitively

I don't think CMs would take kindly to anyone being cavalier about things like rape, incest, etc. But, increasingly, stories are going to such places. Don't be crass or crude about it. Discuss it like an adult. If it devolves, expect less tolerance for it (closure/deletion)

Comment: I suggest you look at this [comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11728/should-we-have-a-policy-on-questions-about-adult-topics-in-sff/11730#comment38488_11730) re: speculative questions, they’re everywhere. We already have numerous metas on NSFW content, and when it’s applicable.

Comment: Since we don't require users to have read/seen a work, how do we draw the line between questions where the OP just legitimately doesn't know if something happened or believes may have happened for some reason? A person largely unfamiliar with the work may not know where to look for such references.

Comment: @phantom42 That's a bit harder, but I'd say that questions asking a speculative adult question, without anything else to back it up, should be closed (not to be confused with downvoted). Because [it's quite possible to craft an answerable question based on speculation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15382/31394)

Comment: I think a problem you, and some of the other users here, have made is that you're trying to treat "adult topic" questions differently to normal questions because you don't appear agree with them. If you're going to close them because they're speculative you then have to apply that guideline to every question on SFF and that leads for very few questions. Remember don't treat close/delete votes as super downvotes.

Comment: Also remember that speculation is appropriate in questions because that speculation is the question itself. Speculation in answers, however, is not appropriate and leads to a poor answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm not arguing that at all. Most SFF questions are on-topic and the standards here are pretty permissive (this site has less closures than any other site I'm on). My point is that we recognize that there's a lot of stories out there that never provide any material on the subject, which naturally reduces the ability to answer the question. And, yes, there is a special sensitivity here (more SO than anything). Or are you saying that I could ask a question speculating about Frodo's sexual habits just because it's fantasy?

Comment: @Machavity Just because something isn't answerable doesn't mean it's off topic, unless it's future works obviously. About Frodo's sexual habits, under the current policy you could and I see no reason why it should be off topic. Is it a good question though? No. On topic and quality are two separate entities.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think the problem is actually that some people feel adult content of any type is fine, so long as it is scifi.stackexchange.com related, and some don't, but rather than try to compromise on a middleground that satisfies both, some people are more focused on fighting perceived censorship.

Comment: Speculative answers can, and do often go off the rails, but [logical speculation in answers is allowed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3484/5184).

Comment: @Beofett I agree but the old linked policy states they are on topic so until a new consensus is reached here they are on topic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The whole point of this meta post is to create new policy - should these questions be on-topic or shouldn't they, or which of them should? So stating they're on-topic according to an old policy is a bit of a red herring. Let's try to create policy here using reasons stronger than "this is what the old policy says" (in any case, the old policy can't be *that* clear since there's been so much disagreement over it), and without recriminations for any past actions on questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Re [this comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11728/should-we-have-a-policy-on-questions-about-adult-topics-in-sff/11731#comment38504_11731) in particular: experience has shown that "adult content" questions DO get treated differently to other questions; we're trying to work out how to deal with that. It's not necessarily true that any guideline agreed upon for these questions has to be applied to all others: we could in principle have special rules for "adult content" questions just as we do for (e.g.) "future works" questions or "story ID" questions.

Comment: Many of the "weird" questions are likely driven by fanfiction. That's not "author's speculation"

Comment: @Randal'Thor Y'know funnily enough I'd worked that out... Also my whole comment is `under the current policy you could and I see no reason why it should be off topic` so I've answered my opinion for, for it being on topic now and in the future. The disagreement comes from people trying to use super downvotes not on whether they are on topic or not, at least that's been my take on it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes they do get treated differently but that's users using super downvotes and nothing else, again my take on it. Special rules for adult content questions though is something I'd personally try and avoid. As soon as you give special rules for a subset of questions you open up room for those rules to be applied broadly and then the site is worse as a whole. As for future works being treated differently that's a different case to this so I don't see how the analogy fits.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To I wasn't meaning the book author's opinions. Edited to clarify

Comment: @Machavity - I know, you meant post author's. That was what my comment applied to. "this is related to fanfics" is considered valid justification on SFF.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Ah, I gotcha

Comment: `we're never shown what happens in the NSFW realm` ~> How are you sure that only NSFW can answer this?

Answer (score 1):

One consideration that appears to be missing from all the discussion here is Hot Network Questions. (This is based on my Ctrl+F of this question's page, so I may have missed some comments that mention it.) Since there are many users who access Stack Overflow, SuperUser, Server Fault, and other professionally oriented sties from work, keeping these questions from loading on their work terminals is desirable and prudent. But if one of them hits the Hot Network Questions, there is no way to control what pages the title loads on across the entire Stack Exchange network (as far as I'm aware). How can this be addressed/controlled?

In the same vein, is there any way for users who wish to avoid these questions to filter them out? Or do participants of this site have to accept the possibility they might be exposed to this type of content?

Comment: Re HNQ: maybe sexual issues could be one of those things like spoilers which are fine to mention in the post body but shouldn't appear in the title? Re filtering: another answer on this meta (now deleted) suggested using [tag:sexuality] and/or [tag:nsfw] tags on all such questions. My feeling is that [tag:nsfw] would be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), but it'd be reasonable to include the existing [tag:sexuality] tag on questions about sexuality (and people can then ignore the tag if they choose).

Comment: To actually respond to your point (I know, that's not what we do here but...) I would treat adult content and the HNQ in the same vein as we treat spoilers. The wording of the _titles_ (which go in the HNQ, among other places) should be handled more strictly than the rest of the post -- nothing overtly NSFW in it, for example. Beyond that, if you're at work and you choose to click on a SF/F link, you take the risk.

Comment: (Discussion about whether or not this counts as an answer has been [moved to main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307707/278659); everyone can feel free to have their say there. I've deleted the long back-and-forth in comments here about it.)

Answer (score -3):

Why not take the Reddit approach and just expect people to use a [nsfw] tag?

Personally, I think it's silly, but it would allow sensitive members to filter out content that has any chance of seeming offensive.

Comment: Because I can then use the NSFW tag to hide any questions I personally deem unsuitable.

Comment: @Valorum:   That is true, but it should be used liberally and if someone is sensitive enough they don't want to see certain content, then they take the penalty of perhaps not seeing other content they wouldn't find offensive.   Too bad.

Comment: Because I can use the NSFW tag to remove *anything* with LGBT content.

Comment: @Valorum:   What do you mean?   Anyone can add or remove tags.   And while I agree it shouldn't be used that way, this is not the site to argue about what some people might find offensive.  You err on the side of filtering.   But either way, presumably a policy would be developed on meta if there's no obvious consensus.

Comment: The very nature of the tag is subjective. Also, and I'm assuming you're aware of this, not everyone feels comfortable (or is even aware that they can) reverting an edit, especially from a higher reputation user.

Comment: @Valorum:  Yes, I acknowledge that.   But that's why we agree it is overly conservative.   Why would we actively refuse to give someone sensitive the tool to hide content that offends them.   That seems like imposing your sensibilities of everyone else.

Comment: Also, you're right that having your edit as the final word on everything would be truly awful.   :)

Comment: The issue isn't that you don't have the tools to hide content that offends you from yourself (top tip, don't look at a site with potentially NSFW content at work) but that you can use the proposed tool for censorship.

Comment: @Valorum, it doesn't enable censorship if 98% of users don't filter.

Comment: @Valorum Why would it be "censorship" to use this tag, more than any other tag which some people might have on ignore? Lots of people ignore [tag:story-identification], but we still want to have that tag. Anyway, anyone abusing a [tag:nsfw] (or any other) tag can easily be flagged/scolded by other users or scolded/suspended by mods. The fact that a feature *could* be abused by malicious users isn't necessarily a reason not to have it, when we have tools to handle malicious users.

Comment: @Valorum: Also *"top tip, don't look at a site with potentially NSFW content at work"*. (1)why should this site be one that must be excluded when it's not the primary purpose or central to the site?  (2)"NSFW" is not a literal expression; it's a shorthand to describe a high bar of *things you might not want to have to explain if someone saw your screen in a professional environment*, but also things that some non-trivially small segment of the population might not want to see at all. Saying "Don't look at it at work if it's 'NSFW' " kind of misses the point of what NSFW represents

Comment: Having an NSFW tag is the thin end of the wedge. Next comes having it ignored by default.