# Please, clarify Answer Deletion privilege clauses

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

Recently, my answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188683/how-was-this-character-able-to-recover-from-a-mortal-wound) was deleted by the community:

> After Tony Stark was stabbed mortally, Doctor Strange made a bargain with Thanos. He offered Thanos the Time Stone in exchange of life of Tony. So, it was actually Thanos who protected Tony Stark from a mortal wound leaving him with a minor injury which he could heal with a spray.

[image]

Per the [privilege page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) for Trusted User (the tier where you gain the privilege to delete things):

> ## Deleting answers
>
> #### When should I vote to delete an answer?
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.
> - The answer is not much more than a link to another page. Link only answers are not allowed on Stack Exchange

My answer is by no means:

- a low quality answer. It is perfectly readable with proper spelling and grammar and punctuations. It doesn't have pornographic or bigotry content.
- not an answer. It isn't a spam or comment or a question.
- a link.

I believe this feature exists mainly to clean up posts from new users.

Talking about answer correctedness (which is subjective most of the time; according to me, my answer is correct), isn't down voting tool designed just for that? If you don't agree with an answer, go ahead to downvote it. If you are an asker, don't accept it.

This also isn't consistent. For example, these famous questions have several highly upvoted answers which don't agree with each other:

[Could I fake death to stop being Force-choked?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked)

[Are all stormtroopers as poor soldiers as the ones in the movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/are-all-stormtroopers-as-poor-soldiers-as-the-ones-in-the-movies)

[How did Dumbledore, or anyone, know Lily had sacrificed herself for Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59582/how-did-dumbledore-or-anyone-know-lily-had-sacrificed-herself-for-harry)

[If Luke Skywalker didn’t want to be found, why did he leave a map?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113497/if-luke-skywalker-didn-t-want-to-be-found-why-did-he-leave-a-map)

Should we start deleting incorrect answers? And, who will decide what's incorrect? If it's asker, should we start deleting answers which don't agree with the accepted answer? All this will ruin the site. There's a reason correctness is handled with checkmark, not "delete other" button.

We had a similar consensus before:

[Is deleting really wrong answers OK according to the rules?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/is-deleting-really-wrong-answers-ok-according-to-the-rules)

But, it's about "really wrong answers". The examples are clear. It's a trivia that Nagini wasn't present in the first Harry Potter book. But, my deleted answer here can't be classified as "Really Wrong Answer".

Comment: @Valorum: Agreed, but I *really* don't like that we're now trying to split hairs between "wrong answers" and "really wrong answers."  I can't see OP's answer so I can't comment on this case in particular, but they might have a point buried in this diatribe.

Comment: @Kevin - My concern here is that OP is combining a perfectly good *specific* question ("***why was my answer deleted?***") with a more general rant about people supposedly abusing their powers and a list of punishments he thinks they should receive. The community generally dislike rants and he's liable to get downvoted, thus cementing his opinion that he's being victimised.

Comment: @Valorum: The concern is not that *you* did something wrong.  The concern is that the way this site operates is perceived as bullying by other people.  We should fix that, and not worry about who should get blamed for it.

Comment: I find it highly offensive that my actions here are essentially being called bullying.

Comment: @Kevin That can never be fixed. You can be the nicest site there is possible, if someone wants to believe they are being bullied they will. It's impossible to please everyone. And the very nature of SFF as part of the SE platform it's going to be hard for people to not feel bullied. We are a "quality" Q/A site after all and not a discussion forum.

Comment: TheWasp and @Valorum: let's not bring any personal stuff into this. *Who* someone is and what they've done in the past should be irrelevant when you're evaluating their posts.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I disagree with your suggestion that we must be rude in order to maintain quality.  The two are independent of each other.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not saying we are rude at all. And in fact I see no rudeness here on the linked post.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: It's rude to ignore site policies and delete an answer that should not have been deleted.

Comment: @Kevin I believe it should have been and in fact we delete incorrect and unsourced answers all the time. I don't see what is rude about that, that is a natural way to maintain quality.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: The votes on this meta Q&A disagree with you.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot `we delete incorrect and unsourced answers` ~> "Incorrect" can be highly subjective. Read the question again. Unsourced you say? 90% of the answers on this site would qualify for deletion. Trivial things don't need to be sourced.

Comment: @Kevin Just re-read with your comment and I'd appreciate it if you didn't twist my words to mean something they don't... `I disagree with your suggestion that we must be rude in order to maintain quality.`

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: That was specifically in reference to "And the very nature of SFF as part of the SE platform it's going to be hard for people to not feel bullied." - which suggests that the SE platform is inherently rude.  It's not.

Comment: @Kevin No it's suggesting the platform is not a discussion forum or even a place to be chatty. Some people find that rude.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not familiar with the film in question but **as far as I can tell the answer should not be subject to deletion under the guidelines for the vote to delete privilege**.

According to Meta.SE

> An answer that is not an answer should be deleted (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question etc...).
>
> Answers that are answers but are factually wrong or are actively bad (say promote SQL Injection) should get downvoted, but not deleted.
>
> <sub>[Oded (former Stack Exchange employee)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/299342), answering "When should I delete an answer?</sub>

The same post is cited elsewhere on Meta.SE, e.g.:

> ## What are the criteria for deletion?
>
> For answers, any post that is [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099) (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice [should be downvoted, not deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264294/1).
>
> <sub>[Community Wiki answer to "How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/299342)</sub>

These guidelines apply to posts in the low quality posts review queue as well. Meta.SE has guidelines on how to review low quality posts (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141857/299342) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/299342)). In general, posts which attempt to answer the question -- even if they are low quality (e.g. unsourced) -- should not be deleted. Only posts which are *extremely* low quality (i.e. offer absolutely nothing of value to the site, are gibberish, don't attempt to answer the question, etc.) should be deleted.

The guidelines given on Meta.SE apply here on Science Fiction and Fantasy as well. We have previously discussed "When should 20kers vote to delete an answer?" and the answer to that question (which currently has a +9/-1 score) says

> ## Use your best judgment
>
> ...
>
> Don't delete in these cases, tho
>
> - **Rude or Spam** - Flag these. When enough people flag them Mods are notified for further action. If 20k users just delete them... nothing
>   else happens.
> - **Meh answers** - In baseball, a tie goes to the runner. In answers, ties should go to the poster. If you can't come up with a good reason
>   for deletion *don't do it*. Don't stretch to delete. [Downvote bad
>   answers and
>   comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).
>
> <sub>[Machavity](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10977/31936)</sub>

That question is linked to "Is deleting really wrong answers OK according to the rules?" and all the positively scored answers instruct or recommend not to delete such answers. [The only answer which suggests that there's no "issue" with deleting such an answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3294/1) currently has a score of -2 and even it notes that

> I believe that outright deletion is a no-no whereas arranging a downvote storm is perfectly acceptable.

The reason we do not delete wrong answers is that

> A wrong answer, downvoted, also conveys information. It tells you, the visitor: *don't do this*. This answer is wrong, and if you are lucky the comments tell you *why* it is wrong.
>
> If we deleted such answers, someone else might make the same mistake.
>
> So instead, we (try to) only delete answers that are not answers (when they are new questions, or comments, or gibberish), or spam, or offensive, etc. We don't delete answers merely because they are incorrect.
>
> <sub>[Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240429/299342), answering "Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?"</sub>

---

Taken together, these sources (as well as the [Trusted User privilege help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) indicate that **there is some judgment required as to what constitutes an "extremely low quality" post (which is subject to deletion) as opposed to merely a low quality post (which should be downvoted, commented on, and/or edited)**. The reason your post was judged to be "extremely low quality" by some users seems to be due to the lack of sources (not that it was wrong), which would be a valid reason to vote to delete (though I disagree with that judgment).

Based on some of the comments (now deleted) it is also possible that at least some users voted to delete based on personal dislike of you and/or because you are a high reputation user who should presumably know how to post a high quality answer. I don't know if that's actually the case, but just to remind everyone: **Vote for the post, not the user.** That's true whether you're voting up or down, voting to close, voting to delete, etc.

Comment: FWIW we delete posts around here all the time for this reason: `Answers that are answers but are factually wrong or are actively bad`. Might not be how the network does things but it surely is what we do. (From my experience anyway, YMMV). Also my VTD was for what I believe is a wrong answer that was unsourced. When questioned the OP refused to add sources so I cast my VTD.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "[W]e delete posts around here all the time for this reason: Answers that are answers but are factually wrong or are actively bad. Might not be how the network does things but it surely is what we do." No, that is against both network and site policy as I've explained in my post. If you are doing that you should cease casting such votes.

Comment: Well against network policy sure. In my experience site culture seems to be to VTD low quality posts that would normally survive elsewhere on the network.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It's also against SFF policy as stated on SFF meta, whether or not reviewers are following that policy. I guess I'll have to keep a close eye on the review queues to make sure reviewers are following the existing policy.

Comment: Well the most recent time this came up the "policy" was unclear: [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11763/58193) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11734/58193). Probably best to quote from the most recent metas in my opinion. The former having no clear votes either way and the latter having two slightly different posts similarly scored.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The latter is more useful but the top scoring answer says, in summary, to only delete content that violates some other policy (e.g. be nice) or objectively adds *no value*. *No value* is similar to the wording I used ("absolutely nothing of value") and sounds like "extremely low quality" to me. The other answer says that low quality content can be removed at the discretion of those with the appropriate privileges, which is in line with what I said that here is some judgment required as to what constitutes an "extremely low quality".

Comment: @Null Well +11 to +9 (at the time of linking) isn't a clear consensus in my mind. Though I think the other answer is stating things more on the lines with how I personally VTD'd this answer in question. Not just "extremely low quality".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot As you admit a lack of clear consensus on the meta you linked to, it is better to follow the guidelines of the meta discussions which *do* have broad consensus (on both main meta and SFF meta). Those are the ones I linked, and they all say to only delete extremely low quality content. The answer under discussion here is not *extremely* low quality in my judgment.

Comment: @Null Probably not extremely no (looking back), but as the linked posts say, answers can always be undeleted. As for which post to follow I tend to look at most recent with a combination of how I see things done in practice. Policies and cultures do change after all even if things were unclear last time it came up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79415/discussion-on-answer-by-null-please-clarify-answer-deletion-privilege-clauses).

Answer (score 21):

I can't see anything in that answer that would qualify for deletion. It's not spam, it's clearly an answer to the question being asked, and there's nothing rude or offensive in it.

I've vote to undelete and so have enough others -- it's been undeleted.

If people want to critique the quality, that's what comments and downvotes are for.

---

For the rest of the meta question -- we've gone over this conversation so many times I can't even read it again. If you think you are being personally targetted by someone on this site, contact the moderators. If you think the moderators are doing a poor job, contact the CMs. If you think the CMs are doing a poor job, this is the wrong site for you.

Comment: FWIW I've generally found here that we are a lot more lax about deleting wrong and poor answers. We do it all the time. It may not be how the network does it but it is certainly how we do it here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I tend to do it where the OP has made an outlandish claim, then point-blank refuses to back it up with evidence.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it's how _some people_ insist on doing things no matter how many times the rest of the community tells them to stop, is a more accurate description.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - that is not within the scope of what Delete function is for. It is VERY VERY clear on the point of "there is little to no scope for improvement", which is a far far stricter standard than "wrong and poor".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79500/discussion-on-answer-by-kutulumike-please-clarify-answer-deletion-privilege-cla).