# Introduce NSFW tag and lock all questions tagged with it

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

This site has stormy relationship with adult questions: [Should we have a policy on questions about adult topics in SFF?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11728/931)

Sometimes, I feel like we are fighting with a virtual problem. Do we have enough data that our site is even visited by non-adults? If yes, they aren't very few in numbers? Or, they aren't involved in mature contents already? In any case, I like the fight, but it's not worth our time.

Also, even when a question doesn't get deleted or closed, it gets heavily downvoted most of the times. Means, lots of adults find it disgusting.

To counter this, I have a proposal. Simply introduce a special NSFW tag and hide all questions tagged with it. Only those users who have checked 18+ age on their profile would be able to see its listing anywhere on the site. If others visit such questions with direct links, show them warnings similar to the one shown on porn sites and let them enable 18+ setting from there.

Comment: I don't mind the idea of content being tagged in general, but the rest of this is asking for infrastructure that simply isn't in place and would not be used over the majority of SE, and probably would not be effective filtering even when it was.

Comment: Creation/use of the tag is fine. People can use their tag preferences to ignore/hide the entire tag from their feed. I'd personally rather that than trying to default everyone to having it hidden.

Comment: "Means, lots of adults find it disgusting". No, what it means is that the question is not properly phrased for the site (i.e. more about the adult content than the SFF elements behind it).

Comment: Declining, as this is incompatible with the site and network terms of service.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth remembering that functionality specific to certain sites ... has limited value.

- Most sites don't really need this
- Age here is a pinky swear thing - primarily used for... well, nothing at all. There *is* a lower age limit for legal reasons, but no one's going to check if you're a very very serious, mature 12 year old pretending to be 20.
- SE rarely, if ever has per user options. It is a performance thing I suppose.
- It is a meta tag. Tags are meant for searchability, and 'NSFW' tells you nothing about the actual question. [SE generally hates meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

If something is truely adult, or not safe for work - flag it.

Answer (score 1):

### The NSFW tag

Not the worst idea. This can already be done. It would be nicer if it didn't count against the five tags, but /shrug.

### I swear I'm an adult

The proposed new functionality seems like overkill, and like a large amount of functionality we're unlikely to get. Instead, users can go to [their tag preferences page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/) and add any tag, such as [nsfw](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nsfw) to their ignored tags.

### So why not do this?

There will still be fights and arguments over what is considered "NSFW", and tagging a question as "NSFW" will have the effect of hiding a question from a portion of the site's audience. A vindictive user could effectively use this to hide questions inappropriately.

Comment: Not least because it helps young visitors find all the dirty questions....

Comment: Or childish adults, like me.