# Can we have meta tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Tags on this site are related with the SFF works mentioned in the question. I propose meta tags which aren’t related with the material, but serves the site.

We can have `18+` tag to restrict access to questions if safe/NSFW browsing is enabled.

We can have `Recently Released` tag (which automatically gets removed from questions after 3 months) to give spoiler warnings before showing question.

We can have `India` tag to promote certain questions to Indian visitors.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11735/3804

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### NO

What qualifies as [18+](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/18%2b) "adult" content is neither the call of the moderators nor the community. Some people believe that [LGBTQ content is "Adult" and should be restricted from access by children](https://www.13newsnow.com/article/news/education/virginia-beach-chesapeake-school-divisions-remove-gender-queer-school-libraries/291-eab299c8-5e98-471b-90e0-703b6742dafc). Some parents are going to discourage their children from reading [twilight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight), others could care less and are much more interested in seeing their children reading *anything*. We aren't going to get involved in any of that debate.

Adding a tag for [recently-released](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recently-released) content is just going to result in a lot of questions being bumped when the tag is removed. Bumping questions is generally discouraged here. It is also likely that there will be disagreements on how long something remains a "recent" release and this could lead to edit wars.

There's absolutely no need for region-specific appeal tags like [india](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india). Questions and tags should be self-explanatory and readers should decide which questions to open based on their own interests, not on an editor's decision on what questions certain people "should" read. If someone wants to read about [stanislaw-lem](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stanislaw-lem), they should know (or can easily learn) that he was Polish. Adding a [poland](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poland) tag is just noise at this point.

For more information on why meta tags are generally considered harmful, read [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on the Stack Overflow blog.